# Масштабируемое изображение

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!

Есть блок. С левой стороны блока текстовый абзац, с правой картинка.

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при уменьшении области просмотра картинка уменьшалась и контент (абзац обтекал ее). На первый взгляд все просто - флоатами расставляем абзац и картинку, картинке задаем размер в процентах и все довольны. Но есть одно НО... - картинка смещена вправо (отрицательный отступ), то есть выходит за пределы блока родителя. Флоат в таком случае отпадает. Как быть?

Верстка адаптивная

**UPD:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/ZV3A4/1/

[image]

Comment: сделайте jsfiddle или jsbin, используйте картинки с http://placehold.it/

Comment: @eicto, выложил. Глянте при случае ... Картинка пока сделана background'ом. Хочется, чтобы обтекала. Флоат, как я уже говорил - не подходит...

Comment: Извините, но я никак не могу понять, в чем же проблема? Почему не подходит обтекание? [ЧЯДНТ][1]

  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/eVt7K/

Comment: @Bars, спасибо, но не подходит. Прочитайте вопрос внимательней и посмотрите на схему ... Необходимо, чтобы картинка выступала за wrapper.

Comment: Ну так она и выступает, на целых 40 пикселей. [А вот она выступает наполовину][1]

  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/eVt7K/3/

Comment: @Bars, обижаете ... Конечно знаю. 

Спасибо, помогли. Я изначально делал по другому - флоатил p style="float: left; и потом пытался двигать изображение, а оно соответственно соскакивало вниз. В общем спасибо.

Сделайте Ваш комментарий ответом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если устанавливать обтекание слева (`float:right`) для картинки, в Хроме (26.0.1410.64 m) и даже IE9 отступы работают как ожидается. Подвел FF: он неправильно (?) понимает отрицательный отступ справа. FF смещает изображение вправо на указанное расстояние, при этом расширяя родительский элемент (отодвигает всю его правую границу).

Поэтому, смещать картинку стоит относительным позиционированием: http://jsfiddle.net/eVt7K/5/

```
.picture {
    width: 50%;

    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: -50px;
    margin-left: -40px;    /* с запасом в 10px - чтобы не вплотную к тексту */
}
```

Лениво искать в спецификации оправдание Лисе, но придумать умом оправдание этому ее поведению я не могу. По-моему, нелогично.